# Microsoft ORCA Answer File

Tags: windows, msi

I am editing a .MSI file and one of the properties is email. Is there a way to pull the users email address automatically so during the install they do not have to enter it?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to automatically retrieve the user's email address during the installation of an MSI file. This is because MSI files are used to install software on a computer, and they do not have access to personal information about the user.

If you want to collect the user's email address during the installation process, you will need to include a field in the installation wizard that prompts the user to enter their email address. You can then store this information in a property of the MSI file, which can be used by the installed software or stored in a configuration file for later use.

One way to do this is to use a custom action in the MSI file to prompt the user for their email address and store it in a property. You can use a custom action to display a dialog box or other user interface element that prompts the user for their email address and then use the MSI API to store the value in a property.